# Кнопки на kotlin +react

Tags: reactjs, ооп, kotlin

Как можно создать кнопку с полем, что бы мы могли в пустое поле записать текст и этот текст записался бы в заранее созданный массив

Comment: а `kotlin` здесь причем?

Comment: Пишем код на  kotlin с подключением React'a

Comment: вопрос не по теме - а у Вас всё на `SSR`?

Comment: Вообще нам преподаватели ничего не говорил,но подозреваю что нет

Comment: @Август, mb [github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-react#creating-a-simple-react-component-with-kotlin) ?

Comment: @qwabra, или https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Building%20Web%20Applications%20with%20React%20and%20Kotlin%20JS/03_A_First_Static_Page

Answer (score 0):

а под `kotlin` сами переделаете **:3**

```js
const myArr = [];

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    this.pushItem = this.pushItem.bind(this);
  }
  
  pushItem() {
      const { current } = this.inputRef;
      
      myArr.push(current.value);
      current.value = '';
      console.log(myArr);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={this.inputRef}/>
        <button onClick={this.pushItem}>push me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```